# T-SQL Select to compute a result row on preceeding group/condition

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

How to achieve this result using a T-SQL select query. 
Given this sample table :

```
    create table sample (a int, b int)

    insert into sample values (999, 10)
    insert into sample values (16, 11)
    insert into sample values (10, 12)
    insert into sample values (25, 13)
    insert into sample values (999, 20)
    insert into sample values (14, 12)
    insert into sample values (90, 45)
    insert into sample values (18, 34)
```

I'm trying to achieve this output:

```
    a           b            result             
    ----------- -----------  ----------- 
    999         10           10 
    16          11           10 
    10          12           10 
    25          13           10 
    999         20           20 
    14          12           20 
    90          45           20 
    18          34           20
```

The rule is fairly simple: if column 'a' has the *special* value of 999 the result for that row and following rows (unless the value of 'a' is again 999) will be the value of column 'b'.  Assume the first record will have 999 on column 'a'.

Any hint how to implement, if possible, the select query without using a stored procedure or function?

Thank you.

António

Comment: SQL Server has no concept of "following" rows.  SQL tables represent unordered sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an id column

```
select cn.id, cn.a
     , (select top (1) b from sample where sample.id <= cn.id and a = 999 order by id desc) 
from  sample as cn 
order by id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Paparazzi

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want if you add a column to specify the ordering:

```
create table sample (
    id int identity(1, 1),
    a int,
    b int
);
```

Then you can do what you want by finding the "999" version that is most recent and copying that value.  Here is a method using window functions:

```
select a, b, max(case when a = 999 then b end) over (partition by id_999) as result
from (select s.*,
             max(case when a = 999 then id end) over (order by id) as id_999
      from sample s
     ) s;
```

Comment: Thank you @GordonLinoff, I see your nice idea, it's almost perfect. However, using max(b) results in a different ouput from expected: the column 'result' has the values 13 and 45 (maximum value for each group, and what is needed is the first - values 10 and 20.

Comment: @AntónioGonçalves . . . Ouch.  That needs the `case` as well, so the value from "999" is the value assigned.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Also check out the solution provided by @Paparazzi.